# "Or rather" vs "in fact" in this context

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english

> The dictator has fled the country, **or rather you can say** we have scared him away.

```
           And
```

> The dictator has fled the country, **or in fact you can say** we have scared him away.

Are they both valid?

Can I use **or rather** and **in fact** here to **make a little correction of what I previously said?**

How would a native speaker say this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid expressions. In my opinion *or rather* (expressing the same thing in a different way) fits better here. *In fact* would be used when restating something in a more explicit way.

The dictator has resigned: in fact, he has fled the country.

Comment: Isn't it a semi-colon that should come after the word 'resigned'? Just a doubt @Kate Bunting. Also can't we consider, "The dictator resigned; in fact, he fled the country", too?